# AngularJS resource dependencies

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS on top of an MVC application.  How can I make my AngularJS app depend on a resource having been loaded? In this case I want to ensure my UserData is loaded BEFORE anything else happens.  I am using UI Router and I know I can set resolve states on individual routes but I dont want to have to add this to every route.  Is there a global way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: you can add a parent state of the entire app and use only one resolve there.
With this approach, the data that resolves will be available for all the children.

Comment: I saw a tutorial on this but it looked like I would have to make every state I ever make a "child state" of this parent state which seemed like a maintenance headache https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c#.akz24o4w9

Comment: You just need to define the parent property on the state definition instead of using dot notation.

Comment: Have you got an example please? Thanks

Comment: When you define your state, define a property call parent with the name that has the resolve. So you create a state with the name 'main' and then in the other states you add parent: 'main'. There are examples in UI-Router docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all data in "run" block and put it in some kind of service wrapper.

Comment: Will the AngularJS app not load anything else until all promises within the run block are resolved?

Comment: Exactly. Other way is to create a service, that will collect all data in background and if requested data is not loaded yet, just place request in front of a queue.

Comment: That is not correct, you can't add a promise to resolve into a run block.